# 'Users' and 'Appearance' have disappeared from dashboard menu

Tags: menus, users, dashboard

Recently when I logged in to edit my website, the Users and Appearance menu items had disappeared from the left hand menu from within the dashboard. Any idea why or how I get them back?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to go on here, but I would check out that Menu Editor you've got there. See if you've ( or someone else ) has hidden Users and Appearance from your user.